# Javascript Access Property From Object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I want to set value of "text" property to "value" property.

Example.html:

```
<script>
    var obj = {
        text: "Hello",
        value: this.text
        /*
        value: function() {
            return this.text;
        }
        */
    };

    console.log(obj.text); // Output: Hello
    console.log(obj.value); // Output: undefined

    // console.log(obj.value()); // Output: Hello
</script>
```

Why?

Comment: why do you want to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bcoz `this` refers to global object in your code. `this` is available inside functions otherwise it will refer to the global object (current execution context)

```
  var obj = {
        text: "Hello",
        value: this
    };

    console.log(obj.text);  // Hello
    console.log(obj.value);  // window
```

but in this case

```
 var obj = {
        text: "Hello",
       value: function() {
            return this.text;
        }
    };

    console.log(obj.text);  // Hello
    console.log(obj.value()); //Hello
```

now `this` in value() refers to your object

Comment: i think this is still undefined

Comment: in the second part `this` will refer to `obj` https://jsfiddle.net/cLd7eft4/1/

Comment: your right, but it is a difference, if he wants the `value` to be a string equal to `text` or if it is a funtion returning that value

Comment: @messerbill i get your point but i was just trying to explain the difference between `this` binding in the 2 codes

Comment: and you succeeded ;)

Answer (score 0):

the `this` keyword in javascript means the context which called the current action. so if you want to achieve your issue do the following:

```
  var obj = {
    text: "Hello"
  };

  obj.value = obj.text;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2zzdnmeb/

in your case `this` would be the `window` object - but still: why do you want to do this? you already have your value